# What there standard sizes for stair steps/treads?

Tags: stairs, treads

I am asking because the treads I am replacing are 44" long (three of them) and the longest I have seen is 43". I think this type is called open at one end.

[image]

Comment: Don't think there is a maximum length, but the longer ones will require more support beams/stringers.  Instead of just one stringer at each end, might need one or more in the centre.

Comment: I just have two stringers and they are fine

Comment: Newer code might have changed the distance allowed between stringers, might be why only finding 43 inchers now.  Can usually just cut a 2x8 to the size you want if in code.

Comment: it will require something to sit on wouldn't it? There is nothing there for three of the steps. The side stringers sit on framing but the middle one will have noting to sit on as the treads are above a crawl space

Comment: I will not remove the old ones as I need to raise them 3/4" each so the new treads will sit on top of the old ones (old nose will be cut)

Comment: So what you want are more like thread covers?  Might still need to make them with 3/4 wood, if sizes in stores don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard length, just IRC code on the height of rise and depth of run on the stairs, even that has a lot of variances.

I believe what you have is an "open riser", although open riser can mean the absence of a riser board as well. The tread you have sketched appears to be a "left hand return tread" without the return piece added.